# Import card.io source code as a modul in Android studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, card.io

I've downloaded the card.io source code and i wish to implement it as a new Android-Library module in my project.

Tried `import -> Module -> chose the source code library`.

> Error:(24, 0) Could not find property 'plugin' on com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension_Decorated@4a00927b.

I'm kind of lost here about how to fix it and make it work.

Comment: the down-vote was very helpful. can i get an answer also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same error, solution was very simple:
clone repository from https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-source, and necessarily init dmz submodule, as it is written in the instructions (First build point). Then specify your sdk and ndk location in local.properties like this:

sdk.dir=/Users/=USER=/Documents/sdk
ndk.dir=/Users/=USER=/Documents/android-ndk-r10e

and run ./gradlew clean assembleDebug.

Now you can attach library as AAR file, or import as modul in your project.

Comment: I did all the steps and i was not able to import as module.

Comment: The difference is that the location of my sdk and ndk are other than yours